# How to get user's current latlong without GPS and internet?

Tags: android

My question is to get location while having no internet and GPS off, is there any way?

Please don't give ans about **GPSTracker** class etc.. I used it..

Please give logical answer only.

no "NETWORK_PROVIDER" and no "GPS_PROVIDER"
is that possible?

Comment: check my answer and try it

Comment: It needs API call means , network needed.. but your ans is good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its not possible, Itried a lot. I didn't found solutions...
Sorry if I am wrong.. Its my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

There is company called IP2Location which maintains a number of databases which can convert an IP address into country, state, city, latitude, and longitude.  Have a look at the following link:

http://www.ip2location.com/databases/db5-ip-country-region-city-latitude-longitude

This database can be useful if you need to get a user's location but you can't assume that he will be able to access either GPS or a web service.

Comment: Is it for paid user?

Comment: There may be a fee to use it in production.

Comment: Yae I found its for paid user... Is there another way? thanks for ans..Tim

Answer (score 0):

I suggest try to use [Google Maps Geolocation Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#errors)
you need POST a request, the the service will return a location with accuracy in meters.

Comment: He mentioned in the question that there is no network access, unless I am misreading it.

Comment: Your suggestion is right bro... but if an only if internet is available..